# How to get struct page info from the ptr and pin the memory using kmalloc or vmalloc?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

I am working on an PCIe/DMA driver. The DMA dest memory is not allocated in the user space, but instead it is allocated thru either vmalloc or kmalloc. I have seen many examples of using get_user_pages_fast to get the struct page info and pin them for user space allocated memory.

In my case, `get_user_pages_fast` (correctly) returns error code -14 complaining bad address (it is obviously not user address).

So, I need to make sure the buffer return by kmalloc or vmalloc is pinned and also want to get the pages behind the memory (like `get_user_pages_fast` does), how to achieve that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: void* ptr = kmalloc(128, GFP_xxx); //DMA destination
//get_user_pages_fast((unsigned long)ptr, 1, 1, pages); this does not work since ptr is not user address; what to do?

Comment: If you need to clarify the question, edit the question, don't post it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

To get `struct page` from any `void *` allocated with `kmalloc()` or `vmalloc()`, You want [vmalloc_to_page()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/mm.h#L617).

The Linux kernel doesn't swap out its own memory, so if you just allocated it and haven't told the memory subsystem that it can be swapped (i.e. that it belongs to a user process), then it should be pinned.

Comment: Sorry for the late update - was tied up on a task. root was correct, but I feel there is a better thing to do to obtain the DMAable memory: dma_alloc_coherent, this step is recommended for allocate dma memory and the user does not need to worry about cache and page lock.

Answer (score 0):

dma_alloc_coherent is what I needed - see comments